# Creating get/set method dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to create a UserDon object, and trying to generate the get and set methods programmatically ( based on Pro Javascript book by John Resig page 37 ), and am testing this on Firefox 3.5

The problem is: in function UserDon, "this" refers to the window object instead of the UserDon object.

So after calling var userdon = new UserDon(...) I got setname and getname methods created on the window object (also setage and getage).

How can I fix this?

```
function UserDon( properties ) {
   for( var i in properties ) {
   (function(){
      this[ "get" + i ] = function() {
        return properties[i];
      };

      this[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
        properties[i] = val;
      };
      })();
   }
 }

var userdon = new UserDon( {
   name: "Bob",
   age: 44
});
```

Comment: Good question if this is an exercise. Otherwise, if you're not doing any additional operations in the getters/setters, you'd hopefully simply use public properties and forgo the method overhead. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `this` value you are using belongs to the auto-invoking function expression you have inside the loop, and when you invoke a function in this way, `this` will *always* refer to the global object.

**Edit:** I missed the fact that the function expression is *trying* to make variable capturing to handle the getter/setter creation inside the loop, but the looping variable `i`, needs to be passed as an argument in order to do it and since the function expression is there, context (the outer `this`) should be preserved:

```
function UserDon( properties ) {
  var instance = this; // <-- store reference to instance

  for( var i in properties ) { 
    (function (i) { // <-- capture looping variable
      instance[ "get" + i ] = function() {
        return properties[i];
      };

      instance[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
        properties[i] = val;
      };
    })(i); // <-- pass the variable
  }
}

var userdon = new UserDon( {
   name: "Bob",
   age: 44
});

userdon.getname(); // "Bob"
userdon.getage();  // 44
```

You can also use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) method to invoke the function expression, preserving the context (the value of `this`) and introducing the looping variable to the new scope in a single step:

```
function UserDon( properties ) {
  for( var i in properties ) { 
    (function (i) { // <-- looping variable introduced
      this[ "get" + i ] = function() {
        return properties[i];
      };

      this[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
        properties[i] = val;
      };
    }).call(this, i); // <-- preserve context and capture variable
  }
}
```

I would also recommend to use an `if (properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) { ... }` inside the `for...in` loop to avoid iterating over user extended properties inherited from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Without the auto-invoking function, both getname() and getage() will return 44, because closure references the last value of the array, which is age, refer to page 29 of the book.

Comment: @portoalet: You are right I missed that point, but that is not enough,  the `i` variable should be passed as an argument to that function, also the `this` value should be preserved, see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the lesser-known
`__defineGetter__("varName", function(){});`
and `__defineSetter__("varName", function(val){});`

Although they are nonstandard [like x-html-replace content-type] they are supported by a majority of the non-ie browsers out there [chrome, firefox]

Syntax would be:

```
benjamin = new object();
benjamin.__defineGetter__("age", function(){
  return 21;
});
```

Or you can approach this with prototyping

```
benjamin = {
  get age()
  {
    return 21;
  }
}
```

Comment: never saw this before. Are you using this yourself?

Comment: I only use it for debugging where a variable is being get/set-ed.  You defineSetter("variableName", outputStackTrace); and it works with css styles as well.  For example, you say `object.style.__defineGetter__("left", outputStackTraceFunction);`  For some reason people don't know about this function.  Probably because its nonstandard?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a better idea to get a generic function with 2 parameters : the name of the property and the value (or only the name for the getter).
And this function would check the presence of a speial function for this property and if there isn't any, it would juste change the property's value (or return it's value for getter).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would code it:-

```
function UserDon( properties ) {
   var self = this;
   for( var i in properties ) {
   (function(prop){
      self[ "get" + prop ] = function() {
        return properties[prop];
      };

      self[ "set" + prop ] = function(val) {
        properties[prop] = val;
      };
      })(i);
   }
 }
```